# How do you enable "#ifndef/#endif" blocks in makefile builds?

Tags: c, makefile, mupdf, ifndef

I'm trying to enable debugging options in MuPDF. For some reason they have used `#ifndef NDEBUG` and `#endif` greying out code I want to use. I searched throughout the library but couldn't find any traces of NDEBUG defined anywhere. I've managed to work around this by adding `#undef NDEBUG` in a header, but I would like to know if there is a more non-intrusive method to do so.

SO, can you enable "#ifndef/#endif" blocks from the makefile?

Also, why would you use `#ifndef` to grey out code? Isn't it supposed to be `#ifdef NDEBUG`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add **-DNDEBUG** to the following 3 variables - **CFLAGS**, **CPPFLAGS** and **CXXFLAGS** in your Makefile to define NDEBUG.
Which is equivalent to adding #define NDEBUG

There are other variations too:

```
-DNBDEBUG=1
```

is equivalent to

```
#define NDEBUG 1
```

And to answer the question of why would someone use #ifndef instead of #ifdef is because it highlights your modifications to the original code much clearly.

For example consider the following code as the original version:

```
int a = 123;
int b = 346;
int c = a + b;
```

And you need to add a macro DO_MULT which will multiply instead - there are 2 ways to do this.

First Variation:

```
int a = 123;
int b = 346;
#ifdef DO_MULT
int c = a *b;
#else
int c = a + b;
#endif
```

Second variation:

```
int a = 123;
int b = 346;
#ifndef DO_MULT
int c = a + b;
#else
int c = a *b;
#endif
```

If you use difftools to see the changes - the second variation will show the diff more clearly compared to the first one.

One more reason why you would use a #ifndef is to DO something in CATCH-ALL-EXCEPT scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

`#ifndef` **won't** omit the code if the flag is defined, hence it's usage. You've managed to include the code using `#undef`.

Both `#ifdef` and `#ifndef` are useful, as justification consider this contrived example: you have a bunch of debug `printf` code that you *only* want to compile into a Debug build, using `#ifdef DEBUG` conditions. In the same executable you also have code that you want to *leave out* of a Debug build. In this case using `#ifndef DEBUG` is your only choice.

You *can* define such flags in the makefile, and you can also try to remove previous definitions by using `-U`. Look for a `CFLAGS` variable in the makefile and add `-UNDEBUG`, or add it directly to the compiler call in the compilation target.

If the flag *is* being defined somewhere in the source tree then this won't help.

Comment: Thank you for telling me about the -U flag